# Protecting some ranges from editing and deleting but allowing to use grouping

Tags: excel, vba

I need to have a macro will protect some ranges in my excel file from editing and deleting.
At the same time I need to use filtering, sorting and grouping.

Have already fund solution for preventing the some cells from deleting:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4224-excel-prevent-deleting-cell-contents.html

Also found a code that was meant to solve the grouping aspect but it's not working for me:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/allow-grouping-option-on-a-protected-worksheet-workbook.479873/

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
.Unprotect "tnskmg"
.EnableOutlining = True
.Protect "tnskmg", contents:=True, userInterfaceOnly:=True
End With

End Sub
```

Do you know what can be possibly a reason the code is not working?

Thanks,
Kasia

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is happening?

Comment: *"Not working"* is no useful error description. What does your code vs. what did you expect?

Comment: Note that `.EnableOutlining = True` will only allow you to open/close groups but not allow you to add new groupings that did not exist yet.